# CSV (huge) to web based database

Tags: mysql, database, csv, export, export-to-csv

We have a 5GB csv file, which is a master list for our business.

There are multiple categories, each containing thousands or records. Our goal is to export each category as its own csv file.

How can we run queries and export data?

Running OSX. Is there software for this (mysql) or should we use a web-based database? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a database. Luckily, 5GB is actually pretty small. Import it into MS Access. No need to spin up a database server yet.